# How to change the label in display_list of a field in the model in django admin?

Tags: python, django, label, django-admin, displaylist

I have a model with some fields with a verbose_name. This verbose name is suitable for the admin edit page, but definitively too long for the list page.

How to set the label to be used in the `list_display` admin page?

Comment: Are you sure you do not want to specify the item in the `help_text` instead of the `verbose_name` of that field?

Comment: Yes, the verbose name is not "that" long, and it is displayed better in the edit page since is a flag. But in the list page, it's occupying too much space

Comment: Can you show you `admin.py` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create custom columns.

For example, there is **`Person` model** below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    age =  models.IntegerField()
```

Now, you can create **the custom columns "my_name" and "my_age"** with `my_name()` and `my_age()` and can rename them with [@admin.display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#the-display-decorator)
as shown below:

```py
@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("my_name", "my_age") 
                  # "my_name" and "my_age" need to be assigned

    @admin.display(description='My name')
    def my_name(self, obj):      # ↑ Displayed
        return obj.name

    @admin.display(description='My age')
    def my_age(self, obj):       # ↑ Displayed
        return obj.age
```

Then, **MY NAME**, **MY AGE** and the values of **"name" and "age" fields** are displayed as shown below:

[image]

Of course, you can assign **"name" and "age" fields** to `list_display` in addition to **the custom columns "my_name" and "my_age"** as shown below:

```py
@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("my_name", "my_age", "name", "age") 
                                          # ↑ Here ↑

    @admin.display(description='My name')
    def my_name(self, obj):
        return obj.name

    @admin.display(description='My age')
    def my_age(self, obj):
        return obj.age
```

Then, **NAME**, **AGE** and the values of **"name" and "age" fields** are displayed as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible that you use `verbose_name` the wrong way, and that you should use [**`help_text=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#help-text) instead:

```
from django.db import models


class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        help_text='here some long help text that this is about filling in the name',
    )
```

If you really want to use a different one for the `list_display`, you can work with a property, like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models


class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        verbose_name='Long name for name field',
    )

    @property
    @admin.display(description='Short name', ordering='name')
    def name_display(self):
        return self.name

    @name_display.setter
    def name_display(self, value):
        self.name = value
```

Then in the `ModelAdmin` you use the `name_display`:

```
from django.contrib import admin


@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name_display']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the description of the headers in a few different ways. "Description" meaning the table headers of the admin list view.

Please see:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

Which describes several methods to customise the headers in the list display view of the admin pages.